# Strange behavior when copy-pasting in libreoffice writer

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, paste

When I try to paste text into the Libreoffice writer, the text to paste appears in various parts of the document.

The problem is that with a multi-page article, when I want to copy a text, a table, a mathematical formula I wrote previously, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, when I paste it where I want it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, it appears in the desired but in previous parts too.

Sometimes what I do is copy the desired text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, call an ASCII text processor, for example gedit, paste it into it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, copy it to gedit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it again into write with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

I am using **Ubuntu Xenial 64 bits** and **Libreoffice 5.1.6.2**.

Comment: How do you paste it?

Comment: You appear to be shouting. Consider altering the upper/lower case ratio. That stray apostrophe is puzzling too.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem. When I paste, the text appears in the intended place. Please edit your question to clearly explain how we can duplicate your problem.

Comment: this has been a bug since 2013 and it's still not fixed, oh my god https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/13204/pasting-problem/

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into problems because LibreOffice writer is pasting the formatting as well as the text. If you don't need to preserve the formatting, you can select "Paste Special..." from the Edit menu (or press ctrl+shift+V) and select "Unformatted text". Note that this will also erase any character-level formatting such as bold, italics, etc.